# hibernate searching case insensitive

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications

Hi I have problem searching function of my web app. I'd want it to be searched in lower case then return appropriate data's needed but my code only accepts correct letter cases. Here are the code. I have 2 ways searching on this

1st String: La Fleur Petrus -> It Returns correct string
2nd : la fleur petrus -> returns empty, why is it?

```
        String sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `wine` WHERE name LIKE '%"+wineName+"%'";

    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql_query);
    query.addEntity(Wine.class);

    return query.list();
```

I also tried this one but failed also.

```
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Wine.class)
            .add(Restrictions.ilike("name", '%'+wineName+'%'))
            .setMaxResults(30);
    return (List<Wine>)criteria.list();
```

Comment: Maybe your database consider the case of the strings.

Comment: collation you mean? I haven't check that...

Answer (score 0):

U can use lower/upper on both sides

`WHERE LOWER(column_name) like lower('%value%');`

Comment: why please share your query after changes.

Comment: String sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `wine` WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%"+wineName.toLowerCase()+"%'"; this is the change..

Comment: just return empty results from that query.

Comment: it works on my phpmyadmin I don't why the results are empty if in actual web page results but if I put correct case accordingly it gives results. `SELECT * FROM wine WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%la fleur petrus%')`